# State message in react not printing to browser correctly

Tags: reactjs, axios, state, fetch-api

I built this mini Fetch API app in React from a tutorial. This is relatively simple, as it doesn't use props and only has everything (code wise) in the App.js file. I will say that this largely works. What I'm trying to achieve is to print an error/not found message to the browser. I will preface this by saying the instructor didn't have us set up any try-catch block to capture a promise error and it appears that happens occasionally.

I'll include the code here. I *do* get the error or success message to print to the console, but can't get it to print to the web browser, but that could be due to the possibility it seems I get an error of the following

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

I'll include the code below. Ideally if no joke is found, it will print that message embedded to the browser. Maybe I do have it coded and configured correctly, but need to account for the failed promise? Any feedback is welcomed. I'm just using React and axios out of this.

Thank you!

```
function App() {
const [state, setState] = useState({
joke: ''
});

useEffect( () => {
fetchData();
},[]); //says to remove it, but that makes the array of jokes keep 
cycling through!! BAD!

const fetchData = async () => {
const result = await 
axios.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
console.log(result.data.value); 
setState({
  ...state,
  joke: result.data.value,
  searchKeyword: '',
  searchUrl: 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query='
});
};

const searchJoke = (ev) => {
console.log(ev.target.value);
setState({ 
  ...state,
  searchKeyword: ev.target.value
 })
}

const fetchMyJoke = async () => {
const result = await axios.get(state.searchUrl + state.searchKeyword)
console.log(result.data.result);

const jokePos = Math.floor(Math.random()*result.data.result.length + 
1);
console.log(jokePos);

**let badmsg = '' + state.searchKeyword;
if (result.data.result.length < 1) {
  badmsg = 'No jokes available on that word';
  console.log(badmsg);
}
else {
  badmsg = 'howdy, enjoy the joke';
  console.log(badmsg);
}**

setState({
  ...state,
  **joke: result.data.result[jokePos].value
   //badmsg: badmsg**
 });
   //  return badmsg;
}

return (
<div className="container">
<div className="row"> 
  <div className="col-6">   
      <h1 className="title">Chuck Norris API</h1>
      <img src={Chuck} height="70%" width="50%" alt="Chuck Norris force 
  of one"/> 
    </div>

  <div className="col-4 searchJokeCol"> 
    <div className="card"> 
      <div className="card-header"> 
      Search for a word
      </div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <input type="text" onChange={searchJoke} />
        </div>
    </div>
  <div >
 <button onClick={fetchMyJoke} className="btn btn-warning btn-lg" >Generate Joke</button>
     </div>
</div>

</div>
<h2 className="subtitle"> Here is the joke!</h2>
**<h4>{state.badmsg} {state.joke} </h4>**
</div>

  );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal CodeSandBox for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `jokePos` should not exceed `result.data.result.length - 1` because array indexes are zero-based.

Example:

```
// assumption: result.data.result = [{ value: ... }, { value: ... }, { value: ... }]

const jokePos = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.data.result.length + 1)
// the max value of jokePos can be 3 now and result.data.result[3] is undefined
```

you should do instead

```
const jokePos = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.data.result.length)
```